# Read response from Flutter Bluetooth device

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

I am using Flutter Blue to write to device (tx in this case), which automatically sends back a response with List on the tx pin (rx in this case). How do I read the response? I'm getting value always as null. The device will send multiple packets of 20 bytes length.

```
getBackgroundFunction() async {
    await _tx.write(setSetting, withoutResponse: false);
    List<int> value = await _rx.read();
    print(value);
  }
```

I also tried:

```
getBackgroundFunction() async {
    List<int> value = await _tx.write(setSetting, withoutResponse: false);
    print(value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter Blue has problems with maintenance. I've opted for Flutter_Reactive_Ble which is supported by developers from Phillips and is very stable. This error does not happen there.

Would recommend anyone who navigated here to do the same.

Comment: i am also using flutter_reactive_ble but the response is very delayed i've checked in android not in ios but one operation takes more than 4 seconds

Comment: Could be a platform specific issue or an issue on your device end. Did you negotiate the MTU package correctly? Can you share more details or better create a question with your reusable code?